# How to automate update process between 2 databases

Tags: mysql, database

I'm quite new to mysql and in database management in general....
I've to solve this scenario:
In the development stage the web site has the database in the local machine and some tables are dedicated to contain information data used by the application ,during the development the records of that tables grow and when we move to production we want to update the production server with the new data...
Can someone advise the best practice to automate the update process from the local to the production database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Content and/or structure? Have you looked at http://flywaydb.org/?

Comment: Yes content and structure...

Comment: I have forgot to mention that we are using JPA so the schema is completely handled by such framework

Answer (score 1):

The road to doing this successfully is to have each database know how far it has migrated.

You should absolute use something like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) to do it. If you have a simple database environment these two will work. Both of these will track changes in version files that the database keep track of.

If you need more complexity, like in a sharded environment, you probably need to roll your own tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention different **.sql** files for each environment like,

**development.sql**,
**staging.sql**,
**production.sql**

And you need to write shellscript to execute this script while deployment process.
Also, you need to maintain one constant to get **current environment**.